# How to change the Picker menu text size in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a `Picker` of style `Menu` and I need to change its text size (the blue text), I tried the `.font(.largeTitle)` modifier but it didn't work.

```
enum Privacy: String, Identifiable, CaseIterable {
    case open = "Open"
    case closed = "Closed"
    var id: String { self.rawValue }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selection = Privacy.open
    var body: some View {
        Picker("Privacy", selection: $selection) {
            ForEach(Privacy.allCases) { value in
                Text(value.rawValue)
                    .tag(value)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
            }
        }
        .font(.largeTitle)
        .pickerStyle(.menu)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the blue label, or the rows which appear when pressed?

Comment: @George I mean the blue label.

Comment: why can't we change text properties like we can change other texts like buttons' s. This is inconsistent

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Remove the `.menu` style and just wrap it in `Menu` instead, with a custom label:

```
Menu {
    Picker(selection: $selection) {
        ForEach(Privacy.allCases) { value in
            Text(value.rawValue)
                .tag(value)
                .font(.largeTitle)
        }
    } label: {}
} label: {
    Text("Privacy")
        .font(.largeTitle)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! it worked.

Comment: The font size setting in the ForEach seem to have zero effect when I try this.

Answer (score 11):

If someone needs to show selected value as label (instead of static text) in this scenario, the following variant can be used

Tested with Xcode 13.2 / iOS 15.2

[image: demo]

```
Menu {
    Picker(selection: $selection) {
        ForEach(Privacy.allCases) { value in
            Text(value.rawValue)
                .tag(value)
        }
    } label: {}
} label: {
    Text(selection.rawValue)
        .font(.largeTitle)
}.id(selection)
```

Comment: I tried the code with Xcode 14.2 / iOS16.2 / iPhone 14 pro simulator. The selection value is not longer updated. After selecting "Closed" "Open is still displayed.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same result simply by applying a scaleEffect modifier on it without having to place it in a menu.

Place
.scaleEffect(1.5)
on the end bracket of Picker() view or its containing Stack if you choose. You will be making the whole picker larger but it is an easy solution for cases like the question (menu style pickers).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Just made it more clear, that should help you. @VikramParimi

Answer (score 3):

I found that the `Menu { Picker() {} }` trick did broken things on Mac (nests the proper menu inside a single item menu). But this slight mod is so far working cleanly across iPhone, iPad, and Mac:

```swift
Menu {
    ForEach(RowLabelType.allCases, id: \.self) { type in
        Button {
            todayTabRowLabels = type
        } label: {
            Text(type.displayString)
        }
    }
} label: {
    Text(todayTabRowLabels.displayString)
}
```

Comment: The sub-menu on macOS is removed by adding .pickerStyle(.inline) to the Picker.